# the two types are not in the same hierarchy: EF Core inheritance of two owned entity types cannot persisted entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

When I save the `Case` entity I get the following error

`"The instance of entity type 'Contact' cannot be tracked as the entity type 'Case.ThirdParty#ContactWithIdNumber' because the two types are not in the same hierarchy."`

I have a `Contact` model

```
public class Contact : ValueObject
{
  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public string Surname { get; private set; }
  public string Tel_Number { get; private set; }
  public string Cell_Number { get; private set; }
  public string Email_Address { get; private set; }
}
```

and `ContactWithId` that inherits from `Contact`

```
public class ContactWithIdNumber : Contact
{
   public ContactWithIdNumber(string name, string surname, string iD_Number, string tel_Number, string cell_Number, string email_Address)
        : base(name, surname, tel_Number, cell_Number, email_Address)
   {
     ID_Number = iD_Number;
   }

   public string ID_Number { get; private set; }
}
```

then I have a `Case` that owns two of the `ContanctWithId` Type `user` and `thirdParty`

```
public class Case
{
   public int Id {get; private set;}
   public ContactWithIdNumber ThirdParty { get; private set; }
   public ContactWithIdNumber User { get; private set; }
}
```

the configure it like so:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Case> config)
{
   config.ToTable("cases", LegalContext.DEFAULT_SCHEMA);
   config.HasKey(o => o.Id);
   config.Ignore(o => o.DomainEvents);
   config.OwnsOne(o => o.ThirdParty);
   config.OwnsOne(o => o.User);
}
```

but when I save the `Case` entity I get the following error `"The instance of entity type 'Contact' cannot be tracked as the entity type 'Case.ThirdParty#ContactWithIdNumber' because the two types are not in the same hierarchy."`

Comment: Please turn this into a [mre] and also tag the exact EF version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

+1, just ran into this. My workaround at the moment is to not use inheritance for the owned entity and just copy all fields from the base type to the child type, which is currently not a problem for me.
I wanted to submit an issue in the ef core repo but I cannot reproduce the issue in a clean solution...